# Moderator declines flag while shortly thereafter user-profile is removed, why decline flag?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam, moderation

I am totally flabbergasted by the actions of the moderator that took the below call.

The image presented in OP's question showed an obvious referral to a commercial party (not shown here). As a non-expert in the addressed language I had the impression that it might be an equivalant of the **Lorem Ipsum** dummy text. Thus as spam fighter I raised a spam-flag.

The flag was "declined" but the question and user-account were removed thereafter!

I believe it was difficult to detect "side-placement" advertisement as for example seen in SOAP-series....

Why decline the flag and give me a bad spot on my flagging stats?

[image]

Comment: The regular flag is for default spam that is easily and obvious to detect. This kind wasn't that easy to spot. It was i.m.h.o. like "side-placement" advertisement in SOAP-series.... I also have to state that there was no code to go through in OP's question.. a preferred for SO questions.

Comment: Hello, lorem ipsum is not spam, it's text placeholder.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier ... that is the whole point...  i.m.o. some user was abusing the respected and well appreciated placeholder construction.

Comment: Which is.. not spam. Hence a declined spam flag. Sorry I just have no idea what your second paragraph means. You saw text that reminded you of lorem ipsum so you flagged the question as spam? That's... Not how it should work..

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier ... you seems not to grasp the issue here. If it was a placeholder text... why would I raise a flag at all?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I don't grasp the issue. Why would you raise the flag if there was no reason to? The second paragraph of the question here suffers from grammatical errors that make it hard to understand what you mean. By all appearances you flagged something because it looked like lorem ipsum.

Comment: obviously there was a reason... "hidden and displaced spam" Hence the "on-hold", then removal of question, followed by removal of user-raccount.. The spam was well hidden!!

Comment: But...not well hidden enough for it to escape moderator's attention, it seems.

Comment: Could it be the flag was declined and then more issues where spotted about the account which caused more action to be taken?

Comment: ..whatever the removal of the account triggered... I do not appreciate a "decline" on my stats for raising a rightful flag as seen from the resulting actions. Or... the "decline" phrase as thrown has past its expiration date.

Comment: @ZF007 You have provided no evidence that your actions were appropriate though, and every indication that the flag merited being declined.  You can't just say you're right for flagging a user for spam with no evidence of them posting spam inappropriately.

Comment: @Servy .. the question is no-longer in google cache... I wish I had screencopied it so I could have provided it in the question itself to prevent this lengthy non-discussion. Perhaps a moderator can make a screener, edit this question and paste it to make the question more useful..because I'm only raising this because I've seen hidden displacement advertisement more often lately and got fedup with "decline" so I stopped reporting "SPAM" at all... is that what people want?

Comment: If you repeatedly get flags declined when you flag the same thing, it is an indication that you are not using the flag correctly, and should stop, yes.

Comment: stop kicking open door Felix...

Comment: You asked a question in a comment, and I answered right after.

Comment: Unfortunately SO doesn't categorize this as spam, only unwanted advertisement should be flagged as spam. Unfortunately SO doesn't categorize this as spam, only unwanted advertisement should be flagged as spam. Unfortunately SO doesn't categorize this as spam, only unwanted advertisement should be flagged as spam. Unfortunately SO doesn't categorize this as spam, only unwanted advertisement should be flagged as spam. Unfortunately SO doesn't categorize this as spam, only unwanted advertisement should be flagged as spam. Unfortunately SO doesn't categorize this as spam, but we do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not a moderator but I [play one on TV](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11#post-54990835)

> Thus as spam fighter I raised the spam-flag.

That's not a spam flag, that's a custom moderator flag. Here's what a spam flag looks like

[image: spam flag]

The problem with your custom moderator flag is it reads like a rant about the post. I can't speak for the moderator who did this, but it's not hard to see why it got a declined. I think, had you been more concise, it might have been marked helpful. Something more like

> I think this might be spam. There's some Lorem Ipsum copied text with a link to an economic site

At least you're being honest that you're not sure it's spam. That's what custom mod flags are for. But starting with "Tough call", misspelling Lorem Ipsum, and equivocating the two at the end is probably what got it declined. How did it get deleted? There's probably other warning signs the mods got that it was a spammer account. Destroying an account deletes all posts by that account.

Some tips for the future

1. Spam has its own flag. If you're reasonably sure it's spam, go with that one. Enough spam flags triggers Community to delete it without direct mod action
2. Custom mod flags are always less precise. A mod has to read and understand you before judging your flag. This wasn't a great flag to begin with.
3. Want some feedback before you flag? Ask [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) or [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Either can help you sort things out before raising any flags

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Especially bullet 3 is handy.

Comment: There's no Lorem Ipsum text anywhere in that question, so even a more well-written flag, while appreciated, would have *also* been declined. For the record, I don't necessarily agree with *"Custom mod flags are always less precise."* It might just be my personal opinion, but any time you think there might be room for misinterpretation, prefer to raise a custom flag and write some explanatory text. Yes, it takes me half a second longer to read it, but it's *more* precise and accurate, increasing the odds I won't miss the thing you thought was suspect.

Answer (score 14):

[The question that you flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151138/what-kind-of-frame-do-i-need-if-i-want-to-add-annotation-on-text) was not spam. For those who can't see deleted posts, here's its content:

[image: Picture of deleted question]

The link was to a GIF demonstrating the effect they desired. I don't see any Lorem Ipsum in this, nor any "spam for economist". The GIF they link to was them showing text selection behavior when viewing an article from The Economist, a fairly large and well-known publication.

The user was deleted when they were later found to be someone evading a question ban via a new account, an issue independent of this post. The post was then deleted automatically due to its negative vote count. This was not spam, and the account was not a spammer, but they were removed for other reasons.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I consider such reference as hidden spam, intrusive towards my private space and therefor a reason for debate to get rid of this offensive form of advertisement. Perhaps a good one for training question on spam detection or contacting the makers to change the heading to "A paper journal" or something?

Comment: @ZF007 You are interpreting the "spam" flag *far* too broadly. It doesn't mean "garbage question". For that, use the "very low quality" flag or one of the "recommend closure" flags. In this particular case, you are still missing the point that this particular question was a legitimate attempt to ask a programming question, and therefore not, by definition, spam. It was a very low-quality question, asking someone to build their entire project for them, but still an attempt to ask a programming question: "I want a Swift program that behaves as shown in the picture."

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you for shedding your lite on this matter. As explained I see it differently and will keep your comment in mind and adjust action for next time when I see such again.